# How to use if statement in playframework 2.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'd like the change the style of tr according the some value, the following demonstrate what I want, but it compile failure. Error message is "illegal start of simple expression", could anyone help one this ? Thanks

```
@session.events.map{ e=>

    <tr class='@if(e.error1!="") "error" else "info"' >
      <td>@e.timestamp</td>
      <td>@e.draftId</td>
      <td>@e.pageName</td>
      <td>@e.mode</td>
      <td>@e.error1</td>
      <td>@e.statusDetail</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: In templates, you need to use curly braces with if and else.

Answer (score 1):

As Marius pointed out:

You could do this:

```
<tr class="@{if(e.error1!="") "error" else "info"}">
```

And everything inside of the

```
@{ }
```

will be properly parsed

Or, you could do this:

```
<tr class="@if(e.error1!="") { error } else { info }">
```

And the stuff inside the curly braces won't be parsed unless you point it by using an `@`

like this

```
<tr class="@if(e.error1!="") { @error } else { info }">
```

And `error` will have to be some previously defined value otherwise you'll get an exception

More on the subject can be [found here on the play's template documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTemplates)

Cheers!